# how can i refresh the php file using javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, function

i am writing a php program  to get images from folder and show it . i want to refresh it . i can not put tht javascript code in the php ?

```
<?php
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action == "view"){
 $entry =$_GET['al'];
```

the  code for refreah

```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
     function refresh(){
     document.images("img1").src="/latimage.php?device=$al&ref=" +  new    Date().getTime();
     var e = document.getElementById("blinker");
     e.style.visibility = ( e.style.visibility == "visible" )? "hidden" : "visible";
     setTimeout("refresh()", 3500);}
 </script>;
```

Comment: Take a look at  your escaping. Then call `refresh()` from within your page

Comment: To answer the question: No, you can't do that. The JS needs to render as part of the HTML page. Read tutorials about HTML and how to include javascript so that you understand what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `echo` to output JavaScript code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'function refresh() {',
        "document.images('img1').src='/latimage.php?device=$al&ref=' +  new    Date().getTime();",
        'var e = document.getElementById("blinker");',
        'e.style.visibility = ( e.style.visibility == "visible" )? "hidden" : "visible";',
        'setTimeout(refresh, 3500)',
    '}',
'</script>';
```

Comment: He uses `echo` for the first line of the function then just types out JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try Like `?> <script> location.reload(); </script> <?php`

Comment: This would just infinitely reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try To like

```
?>
<script>
setTimeout(
    document.images("img1").src="/latimage.php?device=$al&ref=" +  new    Date().getTime();
    var e = document.getElementById("blinker");
    e.style.visibility = ( e.style.visibility == "visible" )? "hidden" : "visible";
, 3500);
</script>
<?php
```